# EDP python mountain lion upgrade renders sklearn module missing

Tags: python, upgrade, osx-mountain-lion, enthought

After upgrading to mountain lion from a lion, the sklearn module that came with my Enthought Python Distribution EDP FREE 32 bits is missing.

```
$ python ASAP_bag_of_words_benchmark_3.py 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "ASAP_bag_of_words_benchmark_3.py", line 4, 
in <module> import features
File "/Users/joseberengueres/Documents/3 - kaggle/ASAP2/Benchmarks/features.py", 
line 14, in <module>
import length_benchmark
File "/Users/joseberengueres/Documents/3 - kaggle/ASAP2/Benchmarks/length_benchmark.py",
line 5, in <module>
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
ImportError: No module named sklearn.ensemble
```

I am sure there must be some quick work arround. The other demos that came with EDP stoped working for the analogous reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok after upgrading to 10.8, you can retry it.

1. remove the old one and reinstall it.
2. export the path and use the python execute file of epd.

Comment: 1. removed EDP with sudo remove-EPD_free-7.3-2
then reinstalled
2. the EDP installation updates the path. Here you can see I reinstalled 4 times. Current points to the EDP intallation.

echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Library/Fra
Any other ideas :( ?

Comment: found a work arround. Install XCode command line tools, then do a sudo easy_install -U scikit-learn, after doing same for numpy.

Comment: Python 2.7.3 |EPD_free 7.3-2 (32-bit)| (default, Apr 12 2012, 11:28:34) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "credits", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
>>> exit()
joseLaptop:Be

Comment: @JoseBerengueres If you know the solution, please post it as an answer and accept it.